# Edit yammer comment using REST Api

Tags: office365api, yammer, rest

When using "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/", I get  errors.First  "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." error.  Second CORS policy blocker error.

```
function editComment(MessagePostId,GroupID) {
var commentData = new FormData();
commentData.append('body', editedComment); //updated comment text
commentData.append('group_id', GroupID); //group id
commentData.append('replied_to_id', MessagePostId); Individual message id 
yam.platform.request({
   url: "https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/messages/"+MessagePostId,
   method: "PATCH",
   data: commentData,
   success: function (res) { 
      alert("The request was successful.");
      console.dir(res);
   },
   error: function (res) {
      alert("There was an error with the request.");
      console.log(res)
   }
})}
```

I tried "POST" as well but facing the same issue again and again.

By any chance, is there any information about REST api for edit comments functionality ?.

Answer (score 1):

Editing is not currently supported by the public API. This is noted in the original release announcement:

> The endpoints will continue to get the most recent version of each
>   message. The data will not include version history or the edit flag.
>   *There will not be endpoints for making edits to messages.*